# Solving equation with two variables in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to solve an equations in one of my google spreadsheets. And I want to perform this function by `GAS`. The script will calculate the value for which another variable will be a specific number. 
The equation is `Y=(X/AVERAGE(B4:J4))*7` where **X** will be calculated by `GAS` and for the value of **X, Y=15.**

Is there any way to perform this operation in google spreadsheet? If yes, please let me know the clue.

Comment: Can you just use a 2nd column with the rearranged equation to solve for X first, and then plug that in?

Comment: @Demis yes, I will do that. Note that X=A6+A5-A4 where A6 and A4 is already given. And value of A5 will be generated by `Google Apps Script`

Comment: If you want, I can share my google sheet file.